# user defined tables/views in drupal

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am new to Drupal,and would like to know if a user can create their own tables in Drupal database and create a connection between a user defined table and Drupal tables?

In other words, my question in general is if one of the purposes of Drupal is also to eliminate the user's need to create/design any tables and and just use the modules in Drupal to work around what they want?

This is the answer to my question I got:

http://drupal.org/node/1925616

Wanted to know more ideas, and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1: Yes, you can do this, using Entities. See [this guide](http://www.istos.it/blog/drupal/drupal-entities-part-1-moving-beyond-nodes) for more info.

For question 2: For the most part, you won't need to create your own tables. You'll get alot of work done by using Drupals UI, creating content types & adding fields for the different use cases that you might have. See http://drupal.org/node/21947.

Comment: thank you for the answer specially the first link. going to try make my school class with a content type and avoid using my own tables if I can